# How to build an standalone shared library in C++ using qmake?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw, qmake

I have written a shared library in C++ using qt creator and QMake

When I compile my project with MinGW compiler, I need the libraries `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` to be copied next to my DLL in order to work. Which has about 1.5 megabytes size.

When I compile my project with MSVC 2015 compiler, I need to install the `Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 x86` on the deployment system. Which has about 13 megabytes size.

My project has less than 100 kiloobytes size so these dependencies are so big.

How can I embed them into my library? or How can I have fewer dependencies to be installed or copied next to my project in Windows 7 or upper?

PS 1: I have read [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows), but the MinGW method was the same as before. And I encountered errors in Microsoft Tools method.

PS 2: Maybe .Net Framework 2.0 is a better option because it is preinstalled on Windows 7 and we can force .Net 4.5 to run it in Windows 8/8.1/10. Don't you agee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just link standard libraries statically. Your DLL size will increase obviously (I hope it isn't a problem) but not that much (<1 MB).

To do that:

If you use MSVC add  /MT to command line (you can find it in project properties window too).

If you use g++ add '--static' .

Comment: /MT did the trick, I have tried it before but I don't know why it worked now. The project was 30 KB and now is 99 KB

Comment: 99KB! Good luck buddy. sometimes /MT will not work if some of other libraries you used statically, weren't build with that flag. it happens. no worries but you have to build them all again with that flag!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that, your project must be set on static or dynamic link, not both of them together.

Comment: You mean there is no way to build a single library and give it to someone else?